# RUBY parse nested JSON Object

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, api, parsing

I have a ruby script that works pretty well.  I'm parsing JSON from an API and passing it into and array.

Most of the top elements parse fine.  But I have a nested object that looks like this after its a hash...

I did and inspect on it and outputted the current data object I'm looking at.

```rb
orf1: ["displayValue", "DNAORF999-N9, DNAORF888-N9, DNAORF777-N9, DNAORF444-N9"]
orf1_inspect: ["displayValue", "DNAORF999-N9, DNAORF888-N9, DNAORF777-N9, DNAORF444-N9"]
orf1: ["isMulti", true]
orf1_inspect: ["isMulti", true]
orf1: ["textValue", "DNAORF999-N9, DNAORF888-N9, DNAORF777-N9, DNAORF444-N9"]
orf1_inspect: ["textValue", "DNAORF999-N9, DNAORF888-N9, DNAORF777-N9, DNAORF444-N9"]
orf1: ["type", "entity_link"]
orf1_inspect: ["type", "entity_link"]
orf1: ["value", ["seq_dfdfdfdfd", "seq_fdfdfd", "seq_fdfdfdd", "seq_jfdfdfd"]]
```

Here is the section of code that returns the above..Let me know if you need more info?

```rb
if row["fields"]["ORF"].nil? || row["fields"]["ORF"].empty?
  orf = nil
else
  row["fields"]["ORF"].each do |orf1|

  puts 'orf1: ' + orf1.to_s
  
  orfinspect = orf1.inspect
  puts 'orf1_inspect: ' + orfinspect
  
  end
end
```

I cant seem to parse oput the individual values.

I need to get the values/data from these fields... displayValue, isMulti, textValue, type, and value

Ive tried all kinds of approaches..  Some give conversion errors.  I can use orf1.first and that works...  but its only part of it...

Even this will get me the header for textvalue

```
orf = orf1[0]["textValue"]
puts 'orf: ' + orf.to_s
```

here is the inspect on `row["fields"]["ORF"].inspect` if it helps..

```rb
{
  "displayValue" => "DNAORF888-N9, DNAORF999-N9, DNAORF444-N9, DNAORF321-N9, DNAORF111-N9, DNAORF777-N9, DNAORF222-N9, DNAORF425-N9, DNAORF122-N9",
  "isMulti" => true,
  "textValue" => "DNAORF888-N9, DNAORF999-N9, DNAORF444-N9, DNAORF321-N9, DNAORF111-N9, DNAORF777-N9, DNAORF222-N9, DNAORF425-N9, DNAORF122-N9", "type"=>"entity_link",
  "value" => ["seq_jddddaA2", "seq_sfgsfff", "seq_osfsffs", "seq_fsdfsd", "seq_fsdfsd", "seq_fsfsfsfs", "seq_sfsfss", "seq_sfsfsf", "seq_sfsfs"]
}
```

This seems to work.  Is this the best approach?

```rb
                row["fields"]["ORF"].each do |key,value|                

                if  key == 'displayValue' 
                        unless value.nil?
                        orf_displayValue=value
                    end
                end
                
                if  key == 'isMulti' 
                        unless value.nil?                       
                        orf_isMulti=value
                    end
                end

                if  key == 'textValue' 
                        unless value.nil?
                        orf_textValue=value
                    end
                end
                
                if  key == 'type' 
                        unless value.nil?
                        orf_type=value
                    end
                end

                if  key == 'value' 
                        unless value.nil?
                    orf_value=value
                    end
                end         
                
            end
        end
```

But I would need to do this for each field.  I feel like there is a better way..

Comment: I'm confused at what it you actually want and what your issue is with dealing with this data. Its a Hash - so you simply call `#values` to get the values.

Comment: @hollecar please add the API output where function does not work and the output that you expecting in your question.

Comment: @max im trying to output data for each field...  All data parsed out for all of these...   displayValue, isMulti, textValue, type, and value...
 
 example:
  header: displayValue
 data:   "DNAORF888-N9, DNAORF999-N9, DNAORF444-N9, DNAORF321-N9, DNAORF111-N9, DNAORF777-N9, DNAORF222-N9, DNAORF425-N9, DNAORF122-N9"
 
 Everything I try either gives me the whole thing or cannot convert integer to string   or symbol to string or something like that...
 
 Can you provide a sample of how I call  #values  ?

Comment: @Chandan
The api function work and I can get all the data...Ive just been unable to parse this one...

Comment: Ive tried this.
```
    orf = row['fields']['ORF'].first['textValue']
    puts 'orf: ' + orf.to_s
```
give this error no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: I tried stuff like this...

```
    row["fields"]["ORF"].each do |orf1|
    orf = orf1.first["textValue"]
````

I get just the string or header textValue returned..

Comment: i can provide any details you need?  Do you want to a sample from the api reference?  It doesn't have the exact same fields and data but its the same endpoint...

Comment: I added a example script to the original question that we can get working to help me with what I need..

Comment: This will actually give me the key and the values...  Now I'm trying to identify each individual one...I think I'm close...

Comment: row["fields"]["ORF"].each do |key, value|
     ##puts "\t#{value["textValue"]} at #{key}"
     puts "key #{key}"
     puts "value #{value}"

Comment: @hollecar please can you also attach working sample data.

Comment: I feel like I have provided all of that...  output the values in textValue...thats it...  plus the other ones...
.....................
DNAORF001-N9, DNAORF002-N9, DNAORF003-N9, DNAORF004-N9, DNAORF005-N9, DNAORF006-N9, DNAORF007-N9, DNAORF008-N9, DNAORF009-N9

Comment: this way I can loop through the records and assign the data to a variable for each

Comment: displayValue = DNAORF001-N9, DNAORF002-N9, DNAORF003-N9, DNAORF004-N9, DNAORF005-N9, DNAORF006-N9, DNAORF007-N9, DNAORF008-N9, DNAORF009-N9

key: isMulti = true

textValue = DNAORF001-N9, DNAORF002-N9, DNAORF003-N9, DNAORF004-N9, DNAORF005-N9, DNAORF006-N9, DNAORF007-N9, DNAORF008-N9, DNAORF009-N9

type = entity_link

value = ["seq_aaaaa", "seq_bbbb", "seq_ccccc"]

Comment: displayValue =  #value  for #key(displayValue)

Comment: textValue = #value  for #key(textValue)

Comment: type = #value  for #key(type)

Comment: value = #value  for #key(value)

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

> can't convert Symbol into Integer

`textValue` is of type `Symbol` and when you are looping over data you end with first key and value which is `displayValue` and `DNAORF004-N9` and inside do end block you are accessing `DNAORF004-N9` index with `textValue` which is `Symbol` which is not possible it should be integer as the error states.

```rb
data = {"displayValue"=>"DNAORF004-N9", "isMulti"=>true, "textValue"=>"DNAORF001-N9", "type"=>"entity_link", "value"=>["seq_fdfdf", "seq_9fdfdfdfd"]}
datasequences = [ :displayValue, :textValue ]
datasequences.each do |textValue|
puts "textValue is #{textValue.inspect}"
    data.each do |key, value|
        puts "\t#{value[textValue]} at #{key}"
    end
end
```

To resolve the issue you can change the code as below:

```rb
data = {"displayValue"=>"DNAORF004-N9", "isMulti"=>true, "textValue"=>"DNAORF001-N9", "type"=>"entity_link", "value"=>["seq_fdfdf", "seq_9fdfdfdfd"]}
datasequences = [ :displayValue, :textValue ]
# changing all keys from string to symbol
data = data.transform_keys(&:to_sym)
datasequences.each do |textValue|
    puts "textValue is #{textValue.inspect}"
    puts "Value: #{data[textValue]}"
end
```

```rb
value = {
    "dnaSequences": [
        {
            "aliases": [],
            "annotations": [],
            "apiURL": "https://url",
            "archiveRecord": nil,
            "authors": [
                {
                    "handle": "dsdsd",
                    "id": "ent_dsdsd",
                    "name": "dsdsd"
                }
            ],
            "bases": "",
            "createdAt": "2020-07-14T21:39:26.991794+00:00",
            "creator": {
                "handle": "dsds",
                "id": "ent_dsdsd",
                "name": "dsdd Fdsdsdso"
            },
            "customFields": {},
            "dnaAlignmentIds": [],
            "entityRegistryId": "MOUSE006",
            "fields": {
                "Identical mouses": {
                    "displayValue": nil,
                    "isMulti": false,
                    "textValue": nil,
                    "type": "part_link",
                    "value": nil
                },
                "Library Constructed By": {
                    "displayValue": "dsdsd",
                    "isMulti": false,
                    "textValue": "dsdsd",
                    "type": "dropdown",
                    "value": "sfso_dsdsd"
                },
                "Library Construction Date": {
                    "displayValue": "2020-06-01",
                    "isMulti": false,
                    "textValue": "2020-06-01",
                    "type": "date",
                    "value": "2020-06-01"
                },
                "Library Description": {
                    "displayValue": "dsdsdds",
                    "isMulti": false,
                    "textValue": "dsdsdsd",
                    "type": "text",
                    "value": "dsdsdsdsd"
                },
                "Library Sample Source": {
                    "displayValue": "dsdsds",
                    "isMulti": false,
                    "textValue": "dsdsdsds",
                    "type": "dropdown",
                    "value": "sfso_dsdsdsd"
                },
                "ORF": {
                    "displayValue": "DNAORF004-N9, DNAORF005-N9, DNAORF008-N9, DNAORF001-N9",
                    "isMulti": true,
                    "textValue": "DNAORF004-N9, DNAORF005-N9, DNAORF008-N9, DNAORF001-N9",
                    "type": "entity_link",
                    "value": [
                        "seq_aaaaaa",
                        "seq_bbbbbb",
                        "seq_ccccc",
                        "seq_ddddd"
                    ]
                },
                "Re-Run ORF?": {
                    "displayValue": nil,
                    "isMulti": false,
                    "textValue": nil,
                    "type": "dropdown",
                    "value": nil
                },
                "Sampling GPS Coordinates": {
                    "displayValue": nil,
                    "isMulti": false,
                    "textValue": nil,
                    "type": "text",
                    "value": nil
                },
                "Sequencing Approach": {
                    "displayValue": "Single Sequence",
                    "isMulti": false,
                    "textValue": "Single Sequence",
                    "type": "dropdown",
                    "value": "gfgf"
                },
                "Sequencing Method": {
                    "displayValue": "gfgf fgfgfg",
                    "isMulti": false,
                    "textValue": "gfgf gfgfg",
                    "type": "dropdown",
                    "value": "sfsogfgfg_irlx6NfZ"
                }
            },
            "folderId": "gfgfg",
            "id": "gfgfgf",
            "isCircular": false,
            "length": 25129,
            "modifiedAt": "2022-04-05T17:06:25.491926+00:00",
            "name": "COPE03-P19",
            "primers": [],
            "registrationOrigin": {
                "originEntryId": nil,
                "registeredAt": "2020-07-14T22:15:09.541243+00:00"
            },
            "registryId": "gfgfgfg",
            "schema": {
                "id": "ps_fdfdfd",
                "name": "mouse"
            },
            "translations": [],
            "url": "hyyps:///COPE/f//edit",
            "webURL": "https://url"
        }
    ]
}

datasequences = [ :displayValue, :isMulti, :textValue, :type, :value ]
result = value["dnaSequences".to_sym].map do |v|
  row = {}
  if v.key?(:fields) && v[:fields].key?(:ORF)
    datasequences.map do |key|
      row[key] = v[:fields][:ORF][key.to_sym]
    end
  end
  row
end
puts result
```

Note: Tested with Ruby 3.0.0

Comment: Here is a full JSON Sample...
https://pastebin.com/s84wXZxi

Comment: @hollecar sure that would be perfect

Comment: I relooked at your answer...  Thanks @Chandan  I will try that to get each value...

Comment: in the sample the   ["fields"]["ORF"]     is the data Ive been trying to parse...

Comment: I already have a large script that loops through each record in 100's of records and pages of records...   this all works... I have a map of dnaSequences   @results["dnaSequences"].map do |row|

Assigned to "row"

im still trying to get each value assigned to a variable..

Comment: How do I add code without making it an answer?

Comment: This works I just need to assign the values to each one?

Comment: data = row["fields"]["ORF"]
    puts data
    datasequences = [ :displayValue, :isMulti, :textValue, :type, :value ]
    datasequences.each do |value0|
     puts "value0 is #{value0.inspect}"
     data.each do |key, value|
      puts "KEY: #{key} VALUE: #{value}" 
     end
    end

Comment: something like this:

Comment: displayValue = :displayValue, 
      isMulti= :isMulti, 
      isMulti = :textValue, 
      type = :type, 
      value = :value

Comment: Then I can use each of those variables in the larger script...

Comment: Okay I think I have it...does this look okay?  or is there a better way I should be doing this...This just assigns textValue's(value)   to variable orf..   But I will do this for each one...

Comment: row["fields"]["ORF"].each do |key,value|
    orf=value if key == 'textValue' || key.nil? 
    puts "ORF: #{orf}" if orf
    end

Comment: @hollecar please check now if it is what you expected.

Comment: did you see my edit at the bottom of the question.  The if and unless statements work...but is that the best approach?

Comment: @hollecar there are various ways to solve the problem you may have heard about it multiple times, it depend on various condition like for eg: you can optimise the repeated part in your code or may choose to leave it as it is for readability

Comment: thank you for your help.  Your comments led me to the solution.